# d3 output includes values outside domain

Tags: d3.js

Why are dates outside the extent being included in the output?

I have start and end dates:

```
Mon Apr 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
Mon Apr 13 2015 23:59:59 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

Define domain and scale:

```
var start = new Date(scope.timetableDate);
var end = new Date(scope.timetableDate);
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
var xDomain = d3.extent([start, end]);
var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain(xDomain).range([0, timetableWidth]);
```

Should `xScale(someDate)` exclude dates outside the extent? For example, should this date be excluded: `Fri Apr 17 2015 05:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)`?

Answer (score 0):

The scale function itself will accept any date. However the return value should fall outside the graph able range if the date is not within the domain given.